# AG-grid enterprise grouping on a field with multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am currently looking at the ag-grid enterprise edition, specifically the grouping functionality.

We are implementing a table where a user can have multiple teams. The table is grouped on teams. For the purpose of this post, I've simplified it to use the example of sports and athletes that are used on the ag-grid website. When an athlete only has one country, the grouping works great, see screenshot:

[Valid result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIaSc.png)

However, in a use case where one athlete may belong to multiple countries the `country` field would have multiple values:

```
{
   ...,
   country: ["United States", "France"],
}
```

What we would like to happen is for the table to generate two groups:

- United States
- France

And then show all athletes with a country of the United States under the United States group and all french athletes under the French group. **Importantly, however,** if a user belongs to both groups they should be shown twice on the table.

For example, **Person D** has two teams, United States and France. On their row data I have set this like so:

```
{
   ...,
   country: ["United States", "France"],
}
```

However, as you can see, this has lead to the following which is not what we're after here:

[image: Unwanted Result]

My question is A) does this functionality exist in ag-grid and B) how do we go about doing it? Ag-grid seems powerful enough to be able to handle this sort of requirement.

Comment: FYI: Since you are using AGgrid Enterprise, you get dedicated support from them

Comment: We haven't purchased a license yet as the ability for us to be able to do this specific piece of functionality will decide if we're going to go ahead with a license.

Comment: Hello - I am also having this issue as well. Were you ever able to solve it? Thank you

Comment: @John well... yes... but you won't like it  We basically took a manual approach with this. In the example above, we would simply iterate over the athletes and split out any athlete that had multiple countries into two distinct records. Didn't find a solution via a native AG grid feature sadly.